# how to use "non" or "no" together with a substantive to make an adjective

Tags: hyphenation, negative-prefixes

I'm trying to describe in a few words the idea of a sign (as a banner, a poster etc.) without any text on it, but only pictures.

Can I use the phrase "non-text" as an adjective? Or maybe "no-text"?
Examples: a non-text sign, or a no-text sign.

Perhaps another obvious adjective that I'm totally missing?

Thanks!

Comment: None of these. Nobody would say any of these things. That is not English.

Comment: Thank you, RegDwigнt! I'm trying to describe in a few words the idea of a sign (as a banner, a poster etc.) without any text on it, but only pictures. I thought I could use the phrase "non-text" as an adjective, so sad I can't... Is there any obvious adjective that I am totally missing?

Comment: I don't agree that 'nobody would say any of these things', but it might be more idiomatic to say 'a picture without text'.

Comment: 'Textless' is in the lexicon.

Comment: Another option is to refer to "a text-free banner" or "a text-free poster."